# Counting the occurence of instances of a certain class in list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list of lists in which I want to count the number of B() and C() instances and am looking for a suitable method to do this. Using collections.Counter() and the .count() function have resulted in strange results, and I suspect I do not fully understand how list of lists work in python, or how lists of class instances work in python.

This is the list of lists:

```
lst = [[B() for w in range(x)] for h in range(y)]
```

with

```
 class A():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

 class B(A):
     def __init__(self, name = "B"):
         A.__init__(self, name)

     def update(self):
         if random.random() < 0.05: 
             return C()
         else: return self

 class C(A):
     def __init__(self, name = "C"):
         A.__init__(self, name)
```

And, I use the below code to randomly change `B()` instances in `lst` into `C()` instances:

```
for row in range(y):
    for column in range(x):
        lst[row][column] = lst[row][column].update()
```

How do I count the number of B() and C() instances in the list?

Comment: Please don't name a `list` `'array'`.

Comment: @JoeIddon, no problem, changed it to list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

You can check what class an `element` is with `isinstance()`.

Here is an example:

```
>>> a = C()
>>> isinstance(a, C)
True
```

So if you have your `list`, you can do:

```
occurrences_of_B = sum(isinstance(i, B) for r in list for i in r)
occurrences_of_C = sum(isinstance(i, C) for r in list for i in r)
```

you can get the occurrences of the `B()` and `C()` `classes`.

Essentially, we are using a `generator comprehension` to apply the `isinstance()` `function` to every `element` in the `list`. We then use `sum` on the `generator` as `True` evaluates to `1` and `False` to `0`, so we will get the total `count`.

*As a side note, although I said it is not good practice to name a `list` `'array'`, it is actually worse to name it exactly `'list'` as this prevents you from being able to use the `list()` `function`! Better would probably be `lst` or `l`. **:)***

Comment: See my `edit` BTW for a little tip. Also, please `up-vote` if this helped! Thank you